# Logout function not working

Tags: php

I want to use a logout function when clicking on a menu item.

If I login and click logout it works, but the moment I click on another page, and then click logout it just adds ?logout at the end of the url.

My code.:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include '../includes/includes.php';
   require('../includes/functions.php'); 
   //make sure user is logged in, function will redirect use if not logged in
   login_required();

   //if logout has been clicked run the logout function which will destroy any active sessions and redirect to the login page
   if(isset($_GET['logout']))
   {
     logout();
   }
?>

<html>
<title>Admin</title>
<header><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"></header>
<body>
    <nav>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="../index.php" target=_blank"">Bekijk site</a></li>
       <li><a href="voegtoe.php">Toevoegen</a></li>
       <li><a href="verwijder.php">Posts</a></li>
       <li><a href="?logout">Uitloggen</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Logout function:

```
//Logout
function logout(){
    unset($_SESSION['authorized']);
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

I have the exact same menu items on any other page, but there it just adds ?logout. The only page that is working is index, so I think something is wrong with how the url is put in the a href.

Comment: add the filename of the script to the href. href="filename.php?logout"

Comment: do you have the php script on every page?

Comment: Your definition <a href="?logout">Uitloggen</a> is definitly wrong, as stated by @Fyntasia . You have to provide a path when defining a link but you are providing a query parameter.

Comment: Because the path "?logout" is interpreted as /?logout (it's relative because it doesn't start with "/", so initialy is set to yourhost.yourdomain/ . Then "?logout" is interpreted as query - parameter, so the path resolved is yourhost.yourdomain/index.php?logout. Because there is no value for logout (as ?logout=true), $_GET["logout] evaluates to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<li><a href="../index.php?logout">Uitloggen</a></li>
```

Better would be:

```
<li><a href="http://www.link-to-site.nl/index.php?logout">Uitloggen</a></li>
```

Comment: Without the ../ it worked, because I also have an index a folder back, and I don't want to navigate there lol. But thanks!

Comment: Yeah, That's why I've posted the alternative, I personally prefer working with absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location:login.php");
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ob_start()` top of the page

```
 function logout(){        
    unset($_SESSION['authorized']);
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
 }
```